# creating a shared library from c++ source file

Tags: java, interface, native

when I tried to create a shared library file using the "cl" command in the vc++ command prompt, it shows a error saying "Can't open include file "jni.h": No such file or directory"... the jni.h is tried to be included in the machine generated header file from java class... i am using this for java navite interface operations... can any one help me...

Comment: thanks i got it... but now another error saying "fatal error C1023: cannot open compiler generated file" –  permission denied...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to tell `cl` where to find `jni.h`. That'll involve using its `-I` option, perhaps like this:

```
-I"C:\Java\what ever\include"
```